# yiibooster confirm modal

Tags: php, yii, modal-dialog

I using the button CONFIRM MODAL (http://yii-booster.clevertech.biz/javascript.html#modals) 
I do not know how to take the boolean variable "confirm" to pass it to a controller

I tray something like this

```
<?php 
if ($model->confirmado == 0) {
    $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
        'label'=>'Confirmar Planilla',
        'type'=>'warning',
        'htmlOptions'=>array(
            'onclick'=>'js:bootbox.confirm("¿Esta seguro que desea confirma la planilla?",
                function(confirmed){ 
                    console.log("Confirmed: "+confirmed);
                    $.ajax({
                        url: CController::createUrl(array("adulto/confirmar")),
                        data: { "term": confirmed.term },
                        success: function(data) { response(data); }
                    });
                })',
        ),
    ));
}?>
```

but didnt work for me....any suggestions?

thanks!!

Comment: You can not call `CController::createUrl()` in javascript.

Comment: ok...what i need to pass "confirm" to some controller?...can u help me?

Comment: here is the solution: if ($model->confirmado == 1) {
                     $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
                       'label'=>'Desconfirmar Planilla',
                       'type'=>'warning',
                       'htmlOptions'=>array('onclick'=>'js:bootbox.confirm("¿Esta seguro que desea desconfirmar la planilla?",
                         function(confirmed){
                         if(confirmed === true)
                         {

Comment: /* the code continue here*/
                         $.ajax({
                         url: "'.$this->createUrl('egb/desconfirmar').'",
                         dataType: "json",
                         data: {
                         confirmar: confirmed,
                         id: "'.$model->id_planilla.'",
                     },
                         success: function(data) { window.location="'.Yii::app()->getRequest()->getUrl().'"; }
                     })}})'
                       ),
                     ));